# slf4j Logger - Historical log files deleted automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have implemented logger in my Java Application.
Log files are getting rotated and getting saved with name on daily basis. Please refer to the attached screenshot for the same. But it seems that that it not saving all of the historical log files, I cannot see historical log files older than 8 days, these are deleted automatically. I can only see log files till 7th March. It will be great if someone could let me know what all additional properties are required or what misconfiguration is done in the configuration, so that I can maintain all of the log files irrespective of the date and time. I want to maintain all of the log files.

[image]

Please refer to the following code and properties file which I have used.

**Logger Implementation in Code:**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

**application.properties file:**

```
server.port = 8080
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true 

#Enable access log.
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true 
#Format pattern for access logs.
#server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
# Date format to place in log file name.
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd
# Enable access log rotation.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true 
# Defer inclusion of the date stamp in the file name until rotate time.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=true 
spring.application.name=DEMO
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=Asia/Kolkata
#jdbc Connection
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=XXXXXXX
spring.jpa.database = POSTGRESQL 


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none 
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl


logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.myapp.app.xyz.controller=INFO
logging.level.myapp.app.xyz.service=INFO
logging.file.name=./logs/app/app_board.log
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#### Hikari connection pool properties #####
spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=3
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=7


spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.file-rotation.
You can configure the history size with `logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history`.

Comment: It is not about history size, the problem here is even if there are no parameters are configured for history rotation or deletion or size, how come the files are getting deleted? Also, is it mandatory to configure that? What if I do not configure? Is it is the default behavior to delete files older than 7 days?

Comment: 7 files is the default for the max-history setting in policy. If you need custom logging, you can always provide your own logback-spring.xml file.

Comment: Let me implement check and mark this answer as correct. Thank you.